# Want to replace raspberry pi with something cheaper and customised

Tags: raspberry-pi

Recently I have built a project using raspberry pi, I am using the USB ports, LAN, 3.5 mm jack headphones, file system in raspberry pi. Now I want to replace raspberry pi with something cheaper and customized, 
how do I replace the raspberry pi?

Please ask me for any more details, because I have no idea what details might be required

Thanks,
AJIT

Comment: Those are the expensive parts of the RPi.

Comment: You want a computer with USB ports, LAN, audio card and file system. Do you want to replace it with something more expensive than a Pi (because that's probably your only option)?

Comment: "Cheaper" and "customized" are mutually-exclusive. The reason the RPi is as cheap as it is is that it is mass-produced, using commodity parts. Plus, you need to account for the non-recurring expenses of doing the customization in the first place.

Comment: A Pi Zero (5$) has almost all you need: file system, usb ports, and can have a wireless lan via wifi adapter (5$). You need to figure out how to extract audio from the hdmi port without spending a fortune.

Comment: @SredniVashtar Audio can still be outputted from a PWM line, and you still have I2S which can deliver audiophile-grade sound.

Answer (score 6):

The quick answer is that you're out of luck. You can get a Pi 2 for about $40. Rolling your own customized unit will involve buying all the parts in very small quantity, not to mention producing the printed circuit board a few at a time. Without large-scale production, you will not be able to beat the price. Furthermore, you'll have to pay for customization. While this can be amortized over many units to spread out the cost, unless you can guarantee the "many units" part the engineering costs will eat you alive.

Comment: Going to have to agree here, you can get something like a model B+ for $30. If you want to build something yourself keep in mind pcb's will cost around $5 per square inch for a two layer board if your ordering from somewhere like osha. Then a decent micro-controller will be $10 or more, just the basic raw materials will push the cost over $30.

Comment: you forget Chinese factories :) they will made the whole raspberry for you for 5$

Comment: @narzan - yes, but in what quantity? And how much will they charge for a "customized" version?

Comment: It's depend on their technology, usually small factories that use light and acid, will cost little, I ordered 300 PCB 5*4CM one face from china and that's cost me 1.30$ for each one, without components, pick up machine will cost you around 2$ for each board, and the components depends on how much your circuit complicated, for my attiny45 the whole board with power circuit around 7$, the power of china :) BTW turkey the same thing

Comment: @narzan - Yeah, but you're missing the point. $5 ea for 300 is 1500 bucks, and for that you can get 40 - 50 "real" pi's. Poster doesn't say how many units he needs.

Comment: That's the lowest number you can order from that factor, hmm well using Pi-Zero will cost less... but not customized...

Comment: Thank you all of you.. i think i have some idea now ..:(

Answer (score 2):

Only thing I've heard of that I believe satisfies your requirements except for the customization part is the [Pine 64](https://www.pine64.com/), but it's a general purpose compute solution so in that regard it's customizable. It's got ethernet, 3.5mm audio jack, and usb. The cost is $15-$29 depending on how much dram you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are doing you may be able to move your project to an old PC which you may find in your local recycling center and can get for very low price. I put together a "used parts only" but server-grade PC by combining components bought used and rejects of my previous upgrades, and the total cost was lower than a Pi 2.